# PyQt. Как правильно центрировать и изменять размер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

У меня:

- есть `MainWindow`
- в `setCenterWidget()` есть `label`
- в `label` - `image`.

Вопрос с позиционированием и изменением размеров.

Я решил сделать минимальный размер `MainWindow`. А для `label` сделать какой-то максимальный, чтобы по бокам было пространство какое-то. Ну и поэтому придется не теряя пропорции уменьшить размер изображения.

К тому же нужно, что бы пропорционально менялся размер, в связи с тем, что пользователь будет изменять своими ручками размер.

Плюс нужно сделать `label` по центру. Я так понял, что если я его одного по центру положу, то `image` добавит пространство и ничего не получиться. Поэтому, кажется, и изображение нужно по центру ставить.

Answer (score 2):

Для размещение по центру используйте метод `setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)`.

Пример:

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QLabel, QScrollArea, QMainWindow


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

label = QLabel()
label.setPixmap(QPixmap('Shingeki_no_Kyojin_ch070_00.png_res.png'))

area = QScrollArea()
area.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
area.setWidget(label)

mw = QMainWindow()
mw.setCentralWidget(area)

mw.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

В `Qt5` виджеты переехали из `QtGui` в `QtWidgets`.

Пример импорта для [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QScrollArea, QMainWindow
```